# idt without gdt using grub

Tags: c, assembly, kernel

im trying to make my own kernel....
my kernel is loaded through grub...which i suppose creates the gdt required for me...so i did not create the gdt myself and continued creating the idt ...

now when i try a divide by zero exception my fault handling method is not called....

i have lidt in my asm file , set the entries into my idt, and after pushing all the registers, i call my fault handler which is never called !
is it possible to create an idt of your own using grub's default gdt ? 
or do i need to create the gdt too ...
source code - https://github.com/pawangogna/pkern

P.S. i am following this tutorial http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/idt.htm

Comment: Where's the division by 0 and what happens actually? Triple-fault?

Comment: now i've even written the code for the gdt and it still doesnt work :( ... the idt code is in idt.c , gdt code in gdt.c, start.asm contains the loading of idt and gdp pointers...isr.c is where i load in the idt entries ( 32 exceptions )

Comment: oh crap...i wrote i=5; and then divided i by 5 instead of dividing by zero ... i feel like a fool...thanks for pointing it out...i wasted an entire day on it !!! thanks @Alex

Comment: Minimal example of protected mode IDT zero division handling: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/9a24f92f36a45abb3f8c37aafc0c3ee9b15563ab/idt_zero_divide.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no division by 0 in the code.